# Two Submit Buttons to Different Controller Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i want to create a form that has two submit buttons, but each one of them submits to a different action of a different controller. I would prefer not to handle this in a single action and redirect according to the submitted button.

Is this possible ? I cannot really find any Rails like solution that does not involve javascript and such dynamic techniques.

Comment: The problem lies within html: you can define only one `action` per `<form>` tag, there isn't a way to have two buttons which point to different `actions` (urls) except to change the `action` attribute via JS.

Comment: @Tass yes, exactly. I'm just wondering what is the 'mainstream' way of handling such situations in Rails. Maybe there is a good way to do it. Well, maybe i could create a couple of button_to's in order to do something like that i guess. But i would like to know if somebody found a better way.

Comment: That will still involve javascript. `button_to` creates a `<form>` tag as well.

Comment: hmm, yes, interesting problem indeed. Since i would not want the same form twice then, it seems that i would have to handle the case with a redirection :/

Comment: Shall I create a nice answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<form>` can [have only one
action](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp), you can
submit a form to one url only. So you need javascript to change the
`action` attribute depending on button or do it on the server.

Comment: hello Reactormonk and @Spyros, how can I achieve this using Javascript? I tried to change action like this `document.getElementById("multi_cont_form").setAttribute("action", receipt_rpts_create_path);`. But the final generated action is prefixed with the current page's URL. eg: loclhost:3000/reports(prefixed automatically)/url_generated_from_javascript.